# Kickstart - Wallpaper configuration

Tags: users, kickstart, wallpaper, gsettings, gnome2

I am writing a kickstart file for an automated & custom CentOS 7 (Gnome 2) installation. I would like **to set the same desktop wallpaper for all my users** (not only root).

I didn't find any good example about setting a desktop wallpaper in a kickstart file ...

I think I have to modify the following code :

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri ${URI}
```

But how do I apply this for all users created during the kickstart ?

Comment: You can replace the default wallpaper image file directly. That won't survive a `yum upgrade` of whatever package puts it there tho.

Answer (score 0):

You can add something to the global `/etc/profile.d` directory that does something like:

```
(sleep 60; your-gsettings-command &> /dev/null) &
```

Morally, I think this is wrong to do to your users. Maybe set a flag and make sure you only do it once ever.

It also won't help if they use KDE.